# Pip install py3.txt in Django patch Tutorial

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I'm having trouble doing

```
pip install -r requirements/py3.txt
```

The following prints out in the terminal

```
  "/private/var/folders/gv/xb_pvkg104x9y3w5cwc978qh0000gp/T/pip-build-4GjEZA/python3-memcached/memcache.py", line 1251
            print("Testing set/get {'%s': %s} ..." % (to_s(key), to_s(val)), end=' ')
                                                                                ^
        SyntaxError: invalid syntax

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gv/xb_pvkg104x9y3w5cwc978qh0000gp/T/pip-build-4GjEZA/python3-memcached
```

The link to the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/contributing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're running a python2 pip trying to install python3 packages. Try `pip -V` to see which version of python it's using.